# possible to edit the movement of navmeshagent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am fiddling with my first pathfinding behaviour. I am using a navmesh and the built in NavMeshAgent and it works great so far!

But I want the agent to take a wider, curved turn (because the agent-object is a vehicle) [Check the illustration below to see what I mean].

If I could edit the navmesh properties at some extend or even create my own navmesh agent, I could say that the agent can only go forward and Slerp the rotation towards the target.

Does anyone know of a editable NavmeshAgent template code??
Or have any other good tips on how to get the navmesh-agent to do a wider curved vehicle-like turn/rotation?

What I have tried:

A empty gameobject with the unity NavMeshAgent component that goes towards a destination target
A object with the vehicle model and a script saying it should only go forward and rotate towards the navmeshagent (this creates a nice and wide vehicle-like turn/rotation)
But the problem with this is that vehicle-object goes of the navmesh and collides with obstacles, because it takes a wider turn than the navmeshagent.

I wish I could shoot like the right side of the picture

Comment: change your navmesh settings and angular speed

Comment: btw there are no pictures in your question ;)